# ADF actionListener doesn't fire in table in a popup

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have a `af:popup` and have a `af:table` in it.
In the table I have a `af:commandImageLink`.

It's placed in a column;
This `commandImageLink` has an `actionListener` that doesn't fire

```
<af:commandImageLink text="commandImageLink 1" 

    id="cil11" 
    icon="/resources/imatges/ver.jpg" 
    partialSubmit="true" 
    immediate="true" 
    actionListener="#{pageFlowScope.MyBean.setNameFilter}"/>
```

I tried puting the `commandImageLink` in the `popup` alone without any `table`, it fires fine;

Very strange indeed.

### Edit:

The code:

```
<af:popup id="cercaTercersCriteria" binding="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.p1}">
                            <af:panelWindow binding="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.pw2}"
                                            id="pw2"
                                            modal="true"
                                            contentHeight="700"
                                            contentWidth="700"
                                            stretchChildren="first">
                              <af:panelGroupLayout binding="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.pgl6}"
                                                   id="pgl6">
                                <af:panelHeader text="panelHeader 1"
                                                binding="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.ph4}"
                                                id="ph4">
                                  <f:facet name="context">
                                    <af:group binding="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.g2}"
                                              id="g2">
                                      <af:commandImageLink text="commandImageLink 1"

                                                           id="cil11"
                                                           icon="/resources/imatges/see.jpg"
                                                           partialSubmit="true"
                                                           immediate="true"
                                                           actionListener="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.setNomeFilter}"/>
                                      <af:panelGroupLayout layout="vertical"
                                                           binding="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.pgl7}"
                                                           id="pgl7">
                                        <af:panelHeader text="SearchTeachersVVO11"
                                                        binding="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.ph5}"
                                                        id="ph5">
                                          <af:query id="qryId5"
                                                    headerText="Search"
                                                    disclosed="true"
                                                    value="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery2.queryDescriptor}"
                                                    model="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery2.queryModel}"
                                                    queryListener="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery2.processQuery}"
                                                    queryOperationListener="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery2.processQueryOperation}"
                                                    resultComponentId="::resId5"
                                                    binding="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.qryId5}"/>
                                        </af:panelHeader>
                                        <af:table value="#{bindings.SearchTeachersVVO11.collectionModel}"
                                                  var="row"
                                                  rows="#{bindings.SearchTeachersVVO11.rangeSize}"
                                                  selectedRowKeys="#{bindings.SearchTeachersVVO11.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
                                                  selectionListener="#{bindings.SearchTeachersVVO11.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"
                                                  rowSelection="single" 
                                                  emptyText="#{bindings.SearchTeachersVVO11.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"
                                                  fetchSize="#{bindings.SearchTeachersVVO11.rangeSize}"
                                                  rowBandingInterval="0"
                                                  id="resId5"
                                                  binding="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.resId5}">
                                          <af:column sortProperty="PefisIdFk"
                                                     sortable="false"
                                                     headerText="#{bindings.SearchTeachersVVO11.hints.PefisIdFk.label}"
                                                     id="resId5c1">
                                            <af:commandImageLink text="commandImageLink 2"
                                                                 id="cil1" icon="/resources/imatges/ver.jpg"
                                                                 binding="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.cil1}"
                                                           partialSubmit="true"
                                                           immediate="true"
                                                           actionListener="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.setNomeFilter}"/>
                                          </af:column>
                                          <af:column sortProperty="name"
                                                     sortable="false"
                                                     headerText="#{bindings.SearchTeachersVVO11.hints.name.label}"
                                                     id="resId5c2">
                                            <af:outputText value="#{row.name}"
                                                           id="ot1"/>
                                          </af:column>
                                        </af:table>
                                      </af:panelGroupLayout>
                                    </af:group>
                                  </f:facet>
                                  <f:facet name="menuBar"/>
                                  <f:facet name="toolbar"/>
                                  <f:facet name="legend"/>
                                  <f:facet name="info"/>
                                </af:panelHeader>
                              </af:panelGroupLayout>
                            </af:panelWindow>
                          </af:popup>
```

Comment: Hm...it's supposed to work. Do you have a `selectionListener` on your `<af:table>` component?

Comment: Can you try adding a `selectionListener="#{bindings.TableCollectionModel.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"`. Just change the "TableCollectionModel" string with the name of the collection model that populates the table

Comment: I added the following:

Comment: selectedRowKeys="#{bindings.SearchTeachersVVO11.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
                                                  selectionListener="#{bindings.SearchTeachersVVO11.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"
                                              rowSelection="single"

Comment: yet it doesn't work, really strange

Comment: In the code you pasted, you have two `commandImageLink`s with id `cil1`, is that the real code or typo? Also, you should turn off auto binding components to backing beans, there is a 99% chance you won't ever need a component reference in your backing bean. One thing you can try is removing `immediate="true"` from command link and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @GingerHead My mistake, I searched the code to see where it was used but didn't notice that extra `1` in id

Comment: I am constructing the page from scratch, Let's see what will happen . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following to resolve:

1. I created new `ViewObject` from scretch
2. I created a `jspx` page from scretch
3. I implimented the `popup` with the table
4. Created a `ManageBean` with my method and implimented it in the `actionListener` of a column of the table

And it suddenly started firing the event charmingly.